# Got a problem with React useContext - returns undefined and have no idea what's wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As title, I am learning React and I decided to use useContext function in my app for the first time. When I try to fetch useContext value, it returns undefined no matter what. I've tried a lot of combinations with .Provider in main file, nothing has changed.

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './index.css'
import Data from './data.json'
import Comment from './Comment'

function App() {

  const [content, setContent] = useState((Data))
  const LoggedUser = React.createContext(Data.currentUser.username)
  const comments = content.comments

  return (
    <LoggedUser.Provider value={Data.currentUser.username}>
      {comments.map((value) => {
        <Comment key={value.id} image={value.user.image.png} username={value.user.username} created={value.createdAt} content={value.content} score={value.score} replies={value.replies} />
      })}
    </LoggedUser.Provider>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Reply from './Reply'

function Comment(props) {
  return (
    <div className='container'>
        <div className='comment'>
            <div className='header'>
                <img src={props.image} alt='image' />
                <span>{props.username}</span>
                <span>{props.created}</span>
            </div>
            <div className='content'>
                {props.content}
            </div>
            <div className='footer'>
                <div className='input'>
                    <img src='./images/icon-plus.svg' alt='plus' />
                    <img src='./images/icon-minus.svg' alt='minus' />
                    {props.score}
                </div>
                <div className='reply'>
                    <img src='./images/icon-reply.svg' alt='reply' />
                    <span>Reply</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {props.replies &&
            props.replies.map((value) => {
                return <Reply key={value.id} image={value.user.image.png} username={value.user.username} created={value.createdAt} content={value.content} score={value.score} replies={value.replies} replyTo={value.replyingTo}/>
            })
            
        }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Comment
```

Reply.js

```
import React from 'react'

function Reply(props) {

  const user = React.useContext(LoggedUser)
  
  return (
    <div className='reply'>
            <div className='header'>
                <img src={props.image} alt='image' />
                <span>{props.username}</span>
                <span>{props.created}</span>
            </div>
            <div className='content'>
                <span>@{props.replyTo}</span> {props.content}
            </div>
            <div className='footer'>
                <div className='input'>
                    <img src='./images/icon-plus.svg' alt='plus' />
                    <img src='./images/icon-minus.svg' alt='minus' />
                    {props.score}
                </div>
                <div className='reply'>
                    <img src='./images/icon-reply.svg' alt='reply' />
                    <span>Reply</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  )
}

export default Reply
```

As it's shown, I am trying to fetch LoggedUser value from App.js in Reply.js, but each time I've tried, I've got this error 'Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

src\Reply.js
Line 5:33:  'LoggedUser' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.'
Help me out guys please, I would really appreciate your help.
If anybody asks, Data.currentUser.username returns the username from file correctly.

Comment: Consider creating your context in a separate file as it's a better practice. Also, in your `Reply` component, you're trying to access a context that is not exported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you haven't imported `LoggedUser` into the `Reply` component

You should be calling `React.createContext` outside of your component, and you should export the result.

Example:

```
import React from 'react'

export const LoggedUser = React.createContext(Data.currentUser.username)

export function App() {

  const [content, setContent] = useState((Data))
  const comments = content.comments

  return (
    <LoggedUser.Provider value={Data.currentUser.username}>
      {/* etc */
    </LoggedUser.Provider>
  )
}
```

```
import React from 'react'
import { LoggedUser } from './App.js' //or wherever it is

export function Reply(props) {

  const user = React.useContext(LoggedUser)
  
  //etc
}
```

It may also help to use named imports instead of default imports if you are exporting multiple things from a file.

Comment: So basically, If I want to use the variable from useContext, I got to import it to the file in which I want to use it?

Comment: Right, you need to import the context that you want to access.

Answer (score 1):

The `LoggedUser` context should be exported from `App.js` and imported to `Reply.js`.

Comment: It might help to provide code snippets in your answer as some readers may not be familiar with context/modules and exports